# Hypothesis testing with a p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

It's believed that at least 75% of workers in a factory are supporting a new initiative from their union.
The survey says that 360/500 workers voted in favour.

Can Ho (null hyp) be rejected with $p=0.75$ with $\alpha$ de $5\%$?

This is my procedure:

$Ho \leq 75%$
$H1 > 75%$

$1-0.75 = 0.25$ in order to get a value from the Z table.
$0.5987$ is that value.

So, since $0.5987$ is below 75, Ho can't be rejected.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Leaving some other issues aside, I'd have called that pre-existing belief $H_0$. Note *in particular* that the belief includes the equality case; you putting the claim into the alternative means you're taking the equality part of the claim and putting it in the hypothesis that doesn't correspond to the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you got wrong p... p isnt a p value. It means a proportion.

You have Ho $\leq 0.75$ and H1 $>0.75$

$t={\frac{p-P}{\sqrt\frac{P(1-P)}{n}}}=-1.549$

$Z=1.645 for 95\%$

Since -1.549 falls in the interval of Ho, Ho isn't rejected.